# Description of the internal decoders of" sinter"

Tags: error-correction, stim

Can anyone explain me what are the "internal decoders" of sinter? What is their decoding method, complexity, advantages, etc.? Is one of the decoders available with sinter better for correlated noise decoding than others?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a link or reference to where you had read about this initially so that anyone trying to answer could get a clearer picture of what you are referring to. To include a link use $[LinkWord](WebAddress)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "internal" decoders aren't publicly available (it's "internal" as in "not public"). Originally, I added them as a hacky way to use some of our internal decoders, if one was present, because at the time there was no mechanism to explain a custom decoder to sinter and because at the time [pymatching was a thousand times slower](https://github.com/oscarhiggott/PyMatching/releases/tag/v2.0.0). Now that those things are both fixed I should probably remove them from the list to avoid confusion.

When I release data for papers, I explain which decoder is used. For example, [Data for "A Pair Measurement Surface Code on Pentagons"](https://zenodo.org/record/6626417) includes stats from "internal_correlated" and in the paper it's explained that this is a correlated minimum weight perfect matching decoder written by Austin Fowler. The specific details of the decoder aren't public but you can see some of Austin's previous publications:

- [Minimum weight perfect matching of fault-tolerant topological quantum error correction in average  O(1) time](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1740)
- [Optimal complexity correction of correlated errors in the surface code](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0863)
- [Pipelined correlated minimum weight perfect matching of the surface code](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.09828)

Comment: Thank you for your help!